# how to delete couchbase bucket data from node's file system?

Tags: linux, couchbase

I am currently using a cluster of couchbase servers 
`couchbase-server-enterprise_2.5.0_x86_64`
comprised of there nods.
As a result of writing too many recorders into the bucket, I've exceeded the cluster memory and 
the nodes went down.

i tried rebooting the machine with the node and restarting it but it won't start.
The reason for this is that it has too many data.
What i would like to do is to clear the bucket by removing it's data from the disk,
however I can't seem to find the location where the data is stored on disk in the couchbase.
Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data for Couchbase (assuming linux) is stored at:

```
/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/data
```

When you say 'too many recorders into the bucket' what do you mean? Just because you have data that is larger than your ram amount doesn't mean the node should go down, it just means that not all documents will be available in ram and the node will sometimes have to fetch from disk (slower).  Unless you've exceeded the cluster capability by a huge margin I don't think this is the cause.

I would investigate before wiping the data on the node + backing the data up.

You can also look at the logs which are located at:

```
/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs
```

How much ram does each of your servers have and how much is assigned to Couchbase?

Comment: thank you. in the end the server suffocated because too much space was assigned to it and to gather with the logs it used up all the disk space on the machine.